# Scroll to right without content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Got a strange layout problem on my website. This only occurred in responsive and only on an article page. On the start page everything is fine, but when i open an article and watch it on my phone or the responsive-emulator from chrome developer-tools, i can scroll to right.

I tryed to debug this, watch the dom-highlighter from the dev-tools but i cant find a reason why there its possible to scroll to right. The insepector shows me no margin or padding.

Startpage: https://pokefans.online

Article-Page: https://pokefans.online/artikel/kyogre-leichter-zu-fangen-mit-neustem-update/434/

Really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one causing the issue is the `.article_trainer_row`, particularly the `.article_traier_text` as it has a fixed width of 335px.

Using width:100% should fix it. (maybe with a max-width so it doesn't go bananas on higher resolution)

Comment: ty very much. I searched in the wrapper, body, etc. but not so deep inside the code. Ty, i have fixed id.